# Is there any relation between Johann Schmidt and Klaus Schmidt?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, x-men-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-first-avenger, x-men-first-class

Klaus Schmidt is the main villain in the film X-Men: First Class and Johann Schmidt is the main villain in the film Captain America: The First Avenger.

They are both seen to be Nazis during World War II so they are of similar age meaning they could possibly be brothers.

I know Schmidt is a common name but it's seems strange that two characters in the Marvel universe would have the same second name and not have a connection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Klaus Schmidt is just an alias not a real name. His real name is [Sebastian Shaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebastian_Shaw_%28comics%29#In_other_media). In movie universe, they have no relation and as per my comics knowledge they are not in any blood relation.

Klaus Schmidt name is just used for the film purpose only it doesn't exist in comics universe and even his Nazi relation is also shown in movie only.